# Alternative syntax for as3 x and y positions

Tags: actionscript-3, properties

I have looked everywhere, because I remember seeing something like this.
Typically I write x and y coordinates out one line at a time, but I've seen it done differently, but I cannot remember how, or figure it out on my own. I will show you some of the syntax I have been trying, and maybe someone will see what I'm getting at.

```
var frog = new Frog;

addchild(frog);
frog.x = 100;
frog.y = 100;
// above works, and is typical for me.

// below is what I'm trying.
addChild(frog);
frog(x:100,y:100);

// or maybe
addChild(frog(100,100)); // doesn't work
```

Basically I'm looking for shorthand. Perhaps I seen it before, but didn't note the context, but It would be nice to trim a lot of my code down. And I hate thinking that I've been doing things the hard way all along.

Answer (score 1):

If your constructor in `Frog` was like this:

```
public function Frog(x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Then:

```
var frog:Frog = new Frog(100, 100);
```

Would work.